# supabase unable to create new user in auth.users table

Tags: supabase-database

Whenever I try to create a new user it says error saving a new user in database and returns 500 error when I checked the logs it says password column does not exist.

I tried to create a user by entering email and password from my nextjs frontend and supabase dashboard both gave the same error.
Log ID
b0927973-9c09-41a7-b1cf-51a3b999e882

Log Timestamp (UTC)
2023-11-30T17:23:16.000Z

Log Event Message
{"component":"api","error":"failed to close prepared statement: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block (SQLSTATE 25P02): ERROR: column "password" of relation "users" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42703)","level":"error","method":"POST","msg":"500: Database error saving new user","path":"/invite","referer":"http://localhost:3000","remote_addr":"192.64.203.242","time":"2023-11-30T17:23:16Z","timestamp":"2023-11-30T17:23:16Z"}

Log Metadata
[
{
"message": null,
"timestamp": "2023-11-30T17:23:16Z",
"__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP": null,
"CODE_FUNC": null,
"instance_id": null,
"status": null,
"_CMDLINE": null,
"method": "POST",
"_SYSTEMD_CGROUP": null,
"CODE_FILE": null,
"EXECUTABLE": null,
"_EXE": null,
"UNIT": null,
"level": "error",
"_COMM": null,
"duration": null,
"issuer": null,
"_LINE_BREAK": null,
"_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": null,
"msg": "500: Database error saving new user",
"action": null,
"login_method": null,
"_UID": null,
"host": "db-vmnexazhojowbofmlual",
"PRIORITY": null,
"_CAP_EFFECTIVE": null,
"_PID": null,
"INVOCATION_ID": null,
"_SYSTEMD_UNIT": null,
"source_type": null,
"SYSLOG_FACILITY": null,
"request_id": null,
"CODE_LINE": null,
"path": "/invite",
"component": "api",
"project": null,
"user_id": null,
"auth_event": [],
"args": [],
"referer": "http://localhost:3000",
"factor_id": null,
"provider": null,
"client_id": null,
"remote_addr": "192.64.203.242",
"_SYSTEMD_SLICE": null,
"_SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID": null,
"header": null,
"_MACHINE_ID": null,
"_AUDIT_LOGINUID": null,
"_TRANSPORT": null,
"_SELINUX_CONTEXT": null,
"MESSAGE_ID": null,
"__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": null,
"metadata": [],
"_STREAM_ID": null,
"metering": null,
"time": null,
"_GID": null,
"_BOOT_ID": null,
"SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER": null,
"_AUDIT_SESSION": null,
"error": "failed to close prepared statement: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block (SQLSTATE 25P02): ERROR: column "password" of relation "users" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42703)"
}
]

Comment: Nobody knows what you are doing, what you are trying, what your stacktrace is, ... Please provide some information.

Comment: Actually I already resolved the issue by just creating a new table inside a new project in supabase.There were some errors in the sql queries i ran before.

Comment: i added the logs which I was getting before the issue is I wasnt able to create a new user the the users table in supabase and I realized there were some queries I ran before which might have caused the problem so I just created a new table in a new project.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers:

The thread owner solved the problem by himself. He created a new table in a new project and it worked.